# WebStorm: Module is not listed in package.json dependencies

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

I have tried importing the NPM package Express into WebStorm to use it using the following method: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/installing-and-removing-external-software-using-node-package-manager.html#d89772e236

Although I have followed the steps, when I use my code:

```
var express = require("express");
var url = require("url");
var http = require("http");
var app;...
```

It underlines express, with the following message:
Module is not listed in package.json dependencies.

I do not have that much experience with WebStorm, so I do not know how to fix this. Would anyone care to explain?

Comment: I've had this error come up, but although the dep isn't in my `package.json`, it can be found in `package-lock.json` as a sub-dependency. So the dependency is available in my project, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put cursor on underlined word, hit Alt+Enter, choose '`Add 'express' to dependencies in package.json`' (or '`Add 'express' to devDependencies in package.json`' if you prefer to have it listed in dev dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Or you have a typo in Package.json.

In that case the rest of the code gives this error for all modules.