# Module 'express' is not listed as dependency in package.json

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am getting `Module 'express' is not listed as dependency in package.json` when executing firebase deploy in the terminal.

When tapping on the link next to it it takes me to this part of my code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { response } from 'express';//here
admin.initializeApp()
```

I have [looked around and could](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074634/webstorm-module-is-not-listed-in-package-json-dependencies) not fined an answer to my question.

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: try `npm i express --save` in the console. It should add express as a dependency automatically.

Comment: @MichaelSorensen still get error

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Can you verify that express is listed as a dependency in your package.json file? There should be a package.json file located in the root of your directory, if there are multiple package.json files then that could be the cause of this issue.

Comment: Actualy now it seems to ahve worked add as answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per comments on the original post:

Typing `npm i express --save` should add express to the dependencies section of your project's package.json file Even if you already have it installed. For example:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    .
    .
    .
    "express": "^4.16.4",
  },

}
```

Answer (score 2):

More specifically for firebase cloud functions, the functions folder has it's own package.json file. You need to run `npm i express --save` from within the functions folde

Answer (score 0):

You need to `npm install --save express` inside *./functions* and be careful not to do it in the root directory.

Additionally, if you are using TypeScript, you need install the type definitions: `npm install --save @types/express`.